# Prevent HTML files downloaded from getting copied from that particular system to another system or getting the script modified?

Tags: html, javascript, copyright, download, copy

How to prevent my HTML files downloaded to a particular system from getting copied from that particular system to another system or getting the script modified?

Is there any tool or method out? Well, I make custom projects using HTML and JavaScript for students and don't want someone to copy or modify the files once downloaded.

If they start copying or modifying, that affects me as I get paid per project. The projects are meant to run in the user's browser only. May it be online or offline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, but that is not possible. They are plain text files, so no way to hide their content. As far as scripts, you can [obfuscate the JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript), but it just makes it harder (but not impossible) for *humans* to read. As mentioned in a comment in that link, "The only way to truly keep something secret is to *not send it to the client*."

Comment: +1 Also note that there are even tools to reverse minification/obfuscation, to varying degrees depending upon the original process used, further eroding how useful that is. It tends to largely be formatting, with variable names still left as less-than-useful "a" "b" etc, but it's still a big difference.

Comment: Thank you. I was also thinking that how can anyone hide those text files. But asked this question to be sure.